# how to remove comments in Apache cxf

Tags: gradle, wsdl, comments, cxf

I want to delete comments in generated java file. I used '-quiet' command but it's not work for me. Is there a way to automate deletion of comments instead of manually selecting and deleting them?

```
wsdl2java {
    wsdlsToGenerate = [
            ['-p','package','-quiet',"wsdl"],
    ]
    generatedWsdlDir = file("$projectDir/src/main/java")
    wsdlDir = file("$projectDir/src/main/resources/wsdl")

    locale = Locale.ENGLISH
}

wsdl2javaExt {
    cxfVersion = "3.1.10"
}
```

Comment: It looks like there are multiple plugins. If you want help I suggest you say which one of these you are using https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=wsdl2java

Comment: I use this plugin. https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/no.nils.wsdl2java

Answer (score 0):

`-quiet` means that no comments will be displayed in the logging of the process.

`-suppress-generated-date` allows to remove the date from the comment but currently there is no additional option. See https://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html and https://github.com/apache/cxf/pull/324 for more information.